# TFS build server duplicate workspaces

Tags: msbuild, windows-server-2012-r2

```
Exception Message: Unable to create the workspace '9_20_NAME' due to a mapping conflict. You may need to manually delete an old workspace. You can get a list of workspaces on a computer with the command 'tf workspaces /computer:%COMPUTERNAME%'. 
Details: The path D:\Builds\NAME is already mapped in workspace 9_22_NAME. (type MappingConflictException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfCreateWorkspace.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

So the above has been plaguing me for just over a week now and on the surface it seems like a simple issue, delete or rename the workspaces and move on. However this issue won't shift that easily.

In short I have tried the following:

- Cleared Workspaces
- Created new build definitions
- Moved the build folder location (e.g. D:\builds\name to D:\builds\name-2)
- Build machine restart
- Uninstalled / Reinstalled TFS (2013 update 3)
- Rebuild the build machine and restored the TFS database

I've pretty much narrowed down the issue to something within TFS itself, but for all the good will I cannot find out what.

It's worth noting that when I delete the workspaces (using TFS sidekicks) the builds will run upto a handful of times. I've not narrowed down exactly what causes change from success to failure, however I can delete all the workspaces then run the builds a couple of times without issue and then suddenly this will come back (around 2-3 builds before constant recurring failure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to edit my build definitions > Source Settings > Build Agent Folder and change this from a hard coded value to $(SourceDir).

A team member pointed me to this answer but I'm none the wiser as to why this setting would cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go to the build machine, search for the old workspace that use the same build definition name, delete that one so the build can create new workspace with the same name again. Check this blog: https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2015/08/25/unable-to-create-the-workspace-due-to-a-mapping-conflict/

Also, try to rename your build definition to something unique to see whether this will fix the issue. http://blog.casavian.eu/2014/04/02/build-workspace-issue/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however as stated above I have already tried clearing the build definitions.

As for the second link, I tried following this but with no luck. I still receive this unable to create workspace error.

Comment: Thanks again, please see my answer for my resolution. That said, I will still likely upgrade TFS version shortly.